# MySQL/MariaDB trigger error

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

MariaDB version 10.1.16.
I can't find what is the problem in the below trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `insert_customer`;
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_customer` AFTER INSERT ON `installations`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE customerId INT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE versionCode INT DEFAULT NULL;
    SELECT c.`id`, c.`version_code` INTO @customerId, @versionCode FROM `customers` c WHERE c.`phone` = NEW.`phone`;

    IF @customerId IS NULL THEN
        INSERT INTO `customers` (`phone`, `imei`, `platform`, `version_code`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES (NEW.`phone`, NEW.`imei`, NEW.`platform`, NEW.`version_code`, NOW(), NOW());
    ELSEIF NEW.`version_code` > @versionCode THEN
        UPDATE `customers` SET `version_code` = NEW.`version_code` WHERE `id` = @customerId;
    END IF;
END;|
DELIMITER ;
```

It says 1064 - syntax error near THEN INSERT but I'm sure the problem is elsewhere. Please help.

Comment: be careful of Error 1172 with your select stmt ... `INTO @customerId, @versionCode`

Comment: @Drew: there's no possibility of error 1172 because customers.phone has unique constraint :) I'm getting 1064 error near INSERT. Any idea? TIA.

Comment: if you supply the create table statements that would help, and the exact error message. That is if the translation of the maria product version isn't very old (most of us are not using maria). So maybe it is a version issue. Someone should be able to attempt to recreate this for you if nothing obvious jumps out.